# Pyside Qmenu Examples

Tags: python, pyside

Does anyone know examples about how to change a qMenu styles of lines separately ( change color of text of line , color of line bg, add underline to any texts inside texts etc. ) or if can't be done , can be solved anyhow ?
Thanks, 
Szabolcs

share my code:

class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
   def **init**(self):
      super(MainWindow, self).**init**()
      self.menus = ['alma','korte','banan','ezmegaz']

```
  acts = []
  self.qmenu = QtGui.QMenu()
  self.hip_fgrp = HipFileGroup( hip_data_file )

  self.hip_fgrp.RemoveRepeats()

  for i,hipf in enumerate(self.hip_fgrp.hipFileArr):
     short_n = hipf.shortname
     # prj = hipf.shortprjname
     prj = ''

     prj = hipf.shortprjname

     if len(hipf.add_hipfolders):
        prj = prj + ' \\ ' + hipf.add_hipfolders[0] 

     action = QtGui.QAction( prj+' \\ '+short_n, self, triggered=self.MenuSelected) 
     action.setData( i)
     acts.append( action)
     # print short_n

  mpos = QtGui.QCursor
  x = mpos.pos().x()
  y = mpos.pos().y()

  for action in acts:
     self.qmenu.addAction(action)

  self.qmenu.show()
  self.qmenu.setGeometry( x-20, y-20, 0, 0)
  self.qmenu.exec_()
```

def MenuSelected( self):
      action = self.sender()
      hipfile_id = action.data()
      hipfile = self.hip_fgrp.hipFileArr[ hipfile_id]
      hipfile.show_all()
      hipfile_last = hipfile.getLastVersion( hipfile.hipfullspec)
      print hipfile_last
      if not in_sublime:
         import hou
         hou.hipFile.load( hipfile_last, hip_accept)

Comment: You should read [the official page on asking on-topic questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). The current state of the question doesn't fit with `Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic`. However, you could re-write to be on topic.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of any easy way.  And it seems to be a long-standing question. But almost anything is possible with a bit of work:

Rather than using a `QAction` in your menu you can use a `QWidgetAction` which lets you customise the widget used to represent the action in the menu. Here I use a `QLabel` which supports rich text.  However, bear in mind that the widget needs to handle the mouse itself (here I call `trigger`).

```
import sys
from PySide import QtGui

class MyLabel(QtGui.QLabel):
    def __init__(self,action):
        super(MyLabel,self).__init__()
        self.action = action

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self,e):
        self.action.trigger()

class Example(QtGui.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Example, self).__init__()

        wAction = QtGui.QWidgetAction(self)
        ql = MyLabel(wAction)
        ql.setText("<b>Hello</b> <i>Qt!</i>")
        wAction.setDefaultWidget(ql)
        wAction.triggered.connect(self.close)

        menubar = self.menuBar()
        fileMenu = menubar.addMenu('&File')
        fileMenu.addAction(wAction)

        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 250, 150)
        self.setWindowTitle('Menubar')    
        self.show()

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
ex = Example()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

In a more fully featured example you might subclass `QWidgetAction` to handle different action contexts, and use different widgets, but this should get you started.

Comment: Thanks, I shared my code because the sollution in my case maybe not will be so easy.So I use the qmenu for just selecting from a list from a 3D application. So I do not need the main window itself. Pls check and tell if you have any idea too. THANKS!! I dont know why the code was broken , if you can help pls tell that answer too. thx

Comment: I don't see why you can't use my solution.  Instead of adding a `QAction` to your menu, add a `QWidgetAction`, like I do.

Comment: Sorry it was a soon reaction. It works. Thanks again.

Comment: Is there any easier sollution in your mind? I without mean changing the cursor , storing the caller's pointer too , put shadow under the window , recreating the focused selected line etc..

Comment: Not really sure what you mean, but no - it's not an easy thing to do.  The standard widget that the QAction builds doesn't support it so you have to do it yourself.  On the other hand, if you just want all the text of the menu to be differently coloured, that's pretty easy: you can just use `QMenu.setStyleSheet`.  Give that a go - it might do enough for you.

Comment: Hi Again, some problem appeared but i could not solve. If you can help that would be nice. So I create a popup the way you wrote and then when i want to fill it again with new fresh data I use the  clear() method. But after new popup lines the action does not call the triggered function. Any Idea? thx